# Common-mode capacitance of operational amplifiers as defined in datasheet

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitance, common-mode

The common-mode input capacitance is modeled as Ccm/2 on each operational amplifier input in https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/input-capacitance-analog-circuits-how-to-compensate-capacitance-op-amps/. However, it is modeled as Cic on each input https://www.edn.com/the-impact-of-input-capacitance-on-op-amp-stability/ , where it is also directly linked to datasheet values.

Is it safe to assume that the common-mode input capacitance given in a datasheet is modeled as Cic on each input separately (4pF on IN+ and 4pF on IN- as in the second referenced link) and is not to be divided by 2 as in the first link? And if so, is the same definition used by different manufacturers?

Comment: Don't assume that two different publications use the same model. Their modelling might be different just as is, as it might serve different purposes, make different assumptions or simply come from a different school of thought. Any question based on assuming that two different models are the same is kind of moot to begin with. You need your datasheet to state what they mean when they specify something.

Comment: I understand it is up to the author to model it. My question is about whether all manufacturers use a standardized definition in their datasheets. It seems TI uses the second definition (https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/archives/b/thesignal/posts/input-capacitance-common-mode-differential-huh) but I can't find anything about Analog for instance.

Comment: and I say: no, you cannot assume that.